# Is analytics.js a wrapper for the Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-api

Does [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) derive its functionality from the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)? In other words, can I use the Analytics API to record the same sort of data that analytics.js records?

If not, what data can be recorded by analytics.js that cannot be inserted using the Analytics API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, analytics.js is a script to construct and send [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide) requests.
You can construct requests to insert required data yourself.